# Add a:hover box-shadow to a picture link

Tags: hover, mouseover, css

I am Trying to add a box shadow a:hover to a facebook icon image.
I thought this would be easy but as usual i was incorrect. 
I am using a child theme in wordpress as I only started a couple of months ago and thought it would be a easy way to start. I thought this may be causing the problem but then i found JSFiddle and was unable to add a box shadow there either.

Code from JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6P2sB/

HTML

Example 1

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
<img class="icon" src="..." alt="facebook icon" align="right" />
</a>
```

Example 2

```
<div class="icon">
<a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="..." alt="facebook icon" align="right" />
</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.icon {
text-align: right;
box-shadow: none ! important;
border-radius: 7px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: -5px;
margin-right: 10px;
height: 45px;
width: 45px;
}

.icon a:hover {
border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly apreciated. Cheers guys!

The link can also be seen at http://www.a2zenyoga.com/events/#link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the `box-shadow` on the anchor. But you need to apply that on `img` when someone hover over `a`. So, your code should looks like this -

```
.icon a:hover img {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I also used .icon img to override existing CSS for images instead of aplying the ! important tag (as Linial pointed out below the ! important tag was overriding everthing)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your fiddle.

I removed

> : none !important;

Which prevents changes to be made, since you include the `!important` which overrides all.

and I changed `.icon a:hover` to `.icon:hover`'

Oh and one last thing, you might want to change `rgba(0,255,0,0.1)` the `0.1` is very low, and might not be visible.

I changed it only so you could see the difference

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shaharlini/6P2sB/1/)**

Comment: Hey thanks, worked really nicely in JSFiddle but not so well on the live website. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).